# How can I keep ghosts out of my machine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've been building a number of redstone circuits lately, and to keep them protected I've been enclosing each entire circuit in obsidian. However, recently I noticed that a zombie managed to spawn in a dark 1x1x2 void within the redstone circuit. I fixed this by placing ceiling slabs to make these voids 1x1x1.5, too small for spawning.

Unfortunately, I came across a part of my design where I have a redstone torch in the top half of a 1x1x2 void, and a redstone wire on the bottom half. I can't fill the void in any way, and I'm afraid monsters can still spawn there. The only solution I can think of is to find a way to add another block of space to the 1x1x2 void where I can place a coal torch, keeping the light level in the void high enough to avoid spawning.

Are there any other tricks or design components that help keep redstone circuitry from becoming a breeding ground for baddies?

Comment: Keep them in the Shell instead

Comment: Is this really a problem?

Comment: @fredley: It can get noisy if you've got a bunch of zombies trapped behind your walls.

Comment: @fredley - *and* they could be dangerous to troubleshoot if something goes wrong with the circuit!

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on stackOverflow?  I usually see debugging questions there...

Comment: @Lee: Since when did Minecraft redstone questions become on topic for us?

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro was a joke...

Comment: @Lee I would imagine it'd be for Stack Overflow if it was a problem with silverfish and spiders.

Comment: @LeeQuarella Zombies aren't a bug, they're a UX problem. :P

Comment: Wouldn't the redstone torch give off light to keep mobs from spawning?

Comment: @Timtech Redstone Torches are too dim to prevent spawning. That's why you often see custom dungeons illuminated with them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to obstruct *every* area in your enclosed redstone circuits.  You can easily place normal torches and/or [Glowstone blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone_Block) throughout the enclosure.  This will also aid in visibility within your ICs.  Redstone *can* be placed on glowstone blocks, but they exhibit interesting properties, so be careful

> Redstone can be put on glowstone, but being a transparent block signals can pass from one block to diagonally another with glowstone "blocking but not blocking" it, making possible nearly instant vertical redstone and new vertical logic gate designs.

Comment: Aha, glowstone! Very interesting. All the more reason for me to work up the nerve to go to the Nether. ;)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot You are correct, Just tried it out in a 1.2.3 creative and it is back in again.. Comment removed :)

Comment: The ability to use glowstone as a block/component of the circuit *and* a light source could help keep my circuits both compact and spawn-proof. You get the check, sir. Now, on to the Nether!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest torches. Keep your circuitry well lit.

Comment: But part of the problem is that they don't have space to place anything...

Comment: @garrett That makes no sense, if there wasn't any space, there wouldn't be any mobs!

Comment: He also says why that's not true in his question. He has a place where there is redstone and a restone torch vertical to each other so he cannot place anything there because they take up the space of the block, but 1x2 mobs like zombies and skeletons can spawn there because the spawn coding in the game doesn't count items such as torches or rails or wire as a spawning obstruction. There has to be a block or light there. True he could just make a 1x2 hole in the wall for a torch but I'm just sayin'!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Why use obsidian? It's just a pain to remove and no more protective from mob spawning than say, cobble or dirt... Also you could have an actual room lit with torches for your circuit instead of fully enclosing it in a shell.

Comment: The reson for using obsidian could be that you want to protect your circuits from creeper explosions.

Comment: @Buhb: That's exactly it. [Once bitten, twice shy.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/48961/15)

Comment: With w previous release and cheats enabled on your world, yo can keep creepers from griefing with `/gamerule mobGriefing false`