# How did my objects disappear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Playing single player (vanilla 1.6.4), I left the game running while I went out for approximately 2 hours. Before leaving I put all of my valuables into 2 chests just in case I died. There was a crafting table in between the two chests. I left the game unpaused in an attempt to farm cacti while I was gone.

I left myself parked in the same room as the two chests.

When I came back, both chests, the crafting table, and the ladder that was used to exit the room I was in were all gone. A few of the stone blocks in the same room also seem to have moved. There is a one block hole in the floor that wasn't there, and there is an extra block in a spot on the wall that wasn't there.

I know that I didn't die because I still have everything that was in my inventory. I know that the game time was advancing because I have more cacti and all of my plants grew.

There is no damage to the room I was in that would indicate an explosion and as far as I know it would not have been possible for any mobs to get in.

Every other section of my house is in the exact same state as it was when I left, including my enchanting room which was in the next room over (no door in between)

How could my chests, a crafting table, and a ladder simply vanish over the course of 2 hours while I left the game running?

I tried using task manager to kill the game and re-launch it but that made no difference.

Comment: Were you in a house or a cave?

Comment: In my house, but my house is built in a hill.

Comment: Do you have roommates? I mean, in real life? Alternatively, did you recently use "Open to LAN"?

Comment: Nope no roomates, and nope wasn't open to LAN. both of those crossed my mind though.

Comment: Oddly enough, we have a related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48961/all-the-contents-of-my-shelter-exploded-killing-me-and-leaving-my-shelter-virtu

Comment: Very late, but that one-block hole sounds like just the right size for Creeper aftermath in stone. And a block in between prevents damage from most explosions, so your chests and crafting table very likely sacrificed themselves to protect you, so to speak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, it sounds like a creeper exploded and you survived it but the chests and ladder did not.

2 hours is plenty of time for it to happen and then have all the items despawn after the chests break.

Comment: Highly unlikely. Items would appear on the ground so you could pick them up. He said that items "moved".

Comment: @YoungGuilo items on the ground disappear after a period of time, they could of all easily dispersed during the two hours he was away if the explosion early after he left. Also he said it "seemed" to move, if the "room" is really a cave it would be difficult to tell the difference between naturally occurring walls and what the explosion left behind.

Comment: Good point I'll ask him about it.

Comment: Or if it is not a cave the walls could be made of a blast resistant material, that explains the single hole in the ground.

Comment: The house is in the side of a hill, Creeper + Hill = complete annihilation.

Comment: walls were plain stone. and the room is very small based on the size of the craters that are left outside when creepers explode I really think I'd see more damage to the walls and floor.

Comment: For plain stone a creeper explosion will dig out a 3x3 hole with potentially a 1x1 hole in the center of that, and that is only if the creeper is directly next to it (like the floor). Each material has a [blast resistance](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Explosion#Blast_resistance) factor that determines how many blocks are destroyed for a explosion.

Comment: would it break the chests even if they were outside of the 3x3 area?

Comment: Yes, chests have a blast resistance of 12.5 where stone has a blast resistance of 30. So a it very easily could be destroyed while the surrounding stone was not.

Comment: The more I look at it and think about it the more this seems like the most likely option. I don't know how he would've gotten in. The walls were somewhat irregularly shaped. Looking at it a bit more I think I found two more stone that got broken that would fit the 3x3, and 1x1 pattern. I'm not 100% sold, but this seems kind of plausible, and is really the only explanation I can think of that isn't completely unreasonable (someone breaking in to my appartment while I was out.)

Comment: Next time you want to do this build a "coffin" by just making a small 1x1x2 room in the wall and block off the wall behind you. That will prevent any creepers from walking up to you and blowing up while you are away (keeps skeletons and zombies from bothering you too).

Comment: A moved block, if it was dirt, may have been an Endermen.

Answer (score 2):

First off, let me just say that [I feel your pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48961/all-the-contents-of-my-shelter-exploded-killing-me-and-leaving-my-shelter-virtu). ;)

Secondly, I wanted to try and add a little more explanation to clear up some lingering doubts about whether or not this was a creeper, since it almost certainly had to be...

You mention a "ladder that was used to exit the room." Did this ladder lead outside or to somewhere creepers could spawn? If so, that must be where the creeper got in. When mobs are pathing around to find you they can actually [climb ladders](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ladders#Usage) if they happen to run into them. I have experienced first-hand a creeper descending a ladder into a room with me and, may I say, it is one of the most terrifying things I have ever witnessed in Minecraft.

I'm guessing you were wearing decent armor, which would explain why you survived the explosion and your nearby chests didn't. Incidentally, do you happen to remember *exactly* what you had in your inventory before you went AFK? If you still had space to hold things, it's quite possible that you may find yourself holding some of the items that *were* in your chests. If they blew up from a creeper explosion, some may have been thrown near enough to you that you picked them up, while the rest sat around until they despawned.

As for the extra block on the wall, I'm guessing it was a dirt or grass block. The only way a block can be added anywhere like that is through being placed by an [Enderman](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman). They can pick up and place back down [certain blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Moving_blocks). If your room is 3 or more blocks high, an Enderman could have easily teleported in there to place it.

Comment: The ladder just leads up into another portion of my house. So as far as I know it should not have been possible for a creeper to be up there. I am not 100% certain on my inventory items. It is possible that one or two of the items ended up in my inventory. After examining the area a bit more I am thinking I was incorrect in thinking that a new block had appeared. I think what actually happened is that a few more blocks than I had initially thought were destroyed which changed my perspective on the area and got me confused.

Answer (score -2):

Might have been an Enderman attack...

Comment: They can't move chests, ladders, or crafting tables.